# An existed Layout can not be resolved to a field

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I have a customised view, and at certain moment of the game I am developing, I want to show a confirmation message to the user. For the confirmation message, I created a new xml file in the layout folder, and in the cistomised view og the game I am trying to refer to that layout as follows:

```
private void showConfirmation() {

LayoutInflater mLayoutInf = LayoutInflater.from(this.mContext);
View confMSG_View = mLayoutInf.inflater(R.layout.confirm_msg, null);
.....
.....
}
```

But, at this step, eclipse underscores the `R.Layout.confirm_msg` with red and says `it can not be resolved to a field`.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `Confirm_msg`  or `confirm_msg` ?

Comment: Check the spelling. In your code you have `confirm_msg` and in your explanation you have `Confirm_msg `. Make sure it is spelled the way it is in your xml

Comment: Also your import can be android.R instead of yourpackage.R

Comment: @GiruBhai all are in small case

Comment: Can you share your xml too?

Comment: @LetsAmrIt Then clean your project and retry.And if not solved then please post your xml layout file also.

Comment: @CemOzer it seems because of the .R after i created the layout eclipse seed to import android.R automatically because i have not imported it. after deletion, it works now

Comment: @GiruBhai it was because of the import of the .R

Comment: Yes there is a bug for a long time in eclipse. Especially if you use "organize imports" this will happen a lot.