# How can I add a layout to my customized view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

I have a class that extends `view` and in it I am creating my customized view. At certain step I want add a `layout` [created here in tis question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426119/an-existed-layout-can-not-be-resolved-to-a-field) to my customized view.

I also referred to some examples but but they seem have the same problem reversed, they have a layout and want to add a customized layout to it.

How can I add a layout to my customized view?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your class should extends `ViewGroup` instead of `View`.

With a `ViewGroup` you will be able to use `addView()` to add inflated layout in your custom view.

For more info on addView take a look at [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams))